# Android Studio / ¿Como poner muchos tabs en Tab Layout sin que se amontonen?

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaría poder lograr tabs cuyos textos se muestren en **una sola línea** y no en dos (**por falta de espacio**) como se podrá ver en la siguiente imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para lograr esto, quiero que se puedan **deslizar los tabs** del lado derecho hacia el izquierdo, para que queden fuera de la pantalla pero que igualmente se pueda **acceder a ellos**. Si aún no me explico bien, adjunto una foto de los tabs de los canales de youtube (pueden comprobar ustedes mismos que se deslizan y **a pesar de ser muchos, todos entran**)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código XML de mi tabbed layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context="com.example.ui.CHAT.fragment_contenedor_chat"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:elevation="7dp"
 android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabss_info_clases"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#b2dfdb"
            app:tabTextColor="#000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#006064"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_info_clases"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**¿Que debería hacer para lograr las tabs tipo YouTube?**

**Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que sea deslizable como en youtube solo debes agregar setear la propiedad `tabMode` como `scrollable` dentro de tu xml.

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Tambien lo podes cambiar por codigo con:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

En algunos casos puede ser util seteralo por codigo y dependiendo el ancho de la pantalla ponerlo scrollable o si tiene espacio de sobra fixed y con los tabs centrados, que es como se usa muchas veces en tablets

Comment: Solucionado hermano! Gracias una vez más por la ayuda!